# Issues with str_getcsv for csv having commas

Tags: php, parsing, csv

Here is my sample csv (having a post name, tags (seperated by commas) and a date:

```
Post, Tags, Date
Hello world, "tag1, tag2, tag3", "10-04-13"
Hello world 2, "tag1, tag2", "10-04-13"
```

Using str_getcsv in php, i get the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Post
    [1] =>  Tags
    [2] =>  Date
Hello world
    [3] =>  \"tag1
    [4] =>  tag2
    [5] =>  tag3\"
    [6] =>  \"10-04-13\"
Hello world 2
    [7] =>  \"tag1
    [8] =>  tag2\"
    [9] =>  \"10-04-13\"
)
```

As you can see, the commas in the tags are messed up when str_getcsv parses the csv.

Any solution for that? Csv was exported from an xls via excel 2007

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your CSV is being exported with backslash-escaped quotes, so the quotes are being treated as part of the data, instead of containers for string data.

`echo` the data you're passing to `str_getcsv`, I'll bet it looks like this:

```
Post, Tags, Date
Hello world, \"tag1, tag2, tag3\", \"10-04-13\"
Hello world 2, \"tag1, tag2\", \"10-04-13\"
```

Somewhere the escapes are being added, you need to find where this is happening and prevent it, doing post-processing on the broken data as it appears above will probably cause you more problems, especially if your CSV contains actual quotes or backslashes anywhere in it.